# Print a message in Triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hi I am new to the sql and I want to know how create a trigger which print the message in the sql console. 
I tried the following code as hello world.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_employee_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

INSERT INTO employees_audit
SET action = 'update',
     employeeNumber = OLD.employeeNumber,
    lastname = OLD.lastname,
    changedon = NOW();
SELECT OLD.employeeNumber;   ////FOR PRINT THE CONSOLE.

END$$
  DELIMITER ;
```

But it gives error. please some one can help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

CREATE TRIGGER before_employee_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

INSERT INTO employees_audit
UPDATE customers
SET //"your code "

dbms_output.put_line('old employerno'||OLD.employeeNumber'); //or Select empno from employees
END

Comment: The DBMS_OUTPUT package enables you to send messages from stored procedures, packages, and triggers. The package is especially useful for displaying PL/SQL debugging information.